# route change in next js 13.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, router

I am using next js 13.4 with app directory. in that I want apply a loader centerally, as route change anywhere inside app loader show. as we know route/navigation don't have event listener.
I have gone through this [Thread on removing event](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42016), but unable to get some useful result.

how to achieve that?

Answer (score -2):

So to fix the problem ,I made a file with Name ***loading.js***  in the app directory's  root.

So when ever you navigate from one page to other , the loading.js runs between them.

Below is for further reading.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming